# Google map, not updating based on current location / position

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-navigation

Had used Google maps on Nokia E72 sometime back, and it used to autoupdate/refresh the map keeping the current location/position updated.

However, used Google maps on Android (latest version of Maps on this device, checked on Google-Play), but the the blue triangle kept on moving on the static map image, and then it went off-screen. It recentred and came back to screen, only once I hit "my location" again. This kind of defeats the purpose. Am I doing something wrong or using the app incorrectly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all make sure you have turned your GPS (if available) and data connection turned on. This helps the device to get your precise location easily.

When using the app, make sure that you **don't touch your devices screen *by mistake***. This often happens even without you knowing it and causes the map to tilt, losing the automatic center alignment of your current position.

Now open the app and press [image]. Then the map will center to your current location. Then tap the location icon again. Now the location icon should move with you. Tap the location icon *again* and then it will look like [image: image2].

Now you should get a more driver friendly view with your location icon moving smoothly. Happy driving!